# Unable to get element which is in under a Iframe in cypress

Tags: cypress

Am using this code
i have used each and every attribute but did not find

[my html code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptlxL.png)

```
cy.get('.gjs-frame')
.then(($iframe) => {
  const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
   cy.wrap($body)
   //cy.get('#v-app')
    //cy.get('.layout')
    //cy.get('.gjs-hovered')
    //.get('.v-application--wrap [data-gjs-type="wrapper"]')
   // .get('[data-gjs-type="wrapper"]')
    //.get('#v-app .v-application--wrap')
    //.get('.v-application--wrap')
   // .get('#v-mount').should('be.exist')

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: [Working with iframes in Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/)

```
const getIframeDocument = () => {
  return cy.get('iframe').its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
};

const getIframeBody = () => {
  // get the document
  return getIframeDocument()
    .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
    .then(cy.wrap);
}

getIframeBody().find(<selector>).should('contain', <content>);
```