# Frame based JSP page is not loaded properly in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to open cypress with an old JSP application having frames. The launching page is loading multiple times and not able to view the buttons or textboxes.I had tried the below options, but nothing worked,

1. 1) Disabling the flag "chromeWebSecurity": false,
   "modifyObstructiveCode":false
2. 2) Defined baseURL in JSON file.
3. 3) Adding remove x-frame-options extensions.

Getting the below error in the browser console,

> Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL:
>   http:///__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js Source Map
>   URL: popper.js.map

Please let me know cypress will work with frame-based pages?

Comment: Do you mean `iframe`?

Comment: yes it's iframe

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148770/unable-to-get-element-which-is-in-under-a-iframe-in-cypress/62149357#62149357) help

Comment: No, The page is not loading properly. If it was loaded properly, we can manage these...The login page has 3 main iframes, the page is reloading inside each(Kind of nested one) buttons and textboxes are hidden. It is working fine in any browser... It working in Selenium and QTP.