# Unable to Interact with iframe in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a pop-up that won't close unless the user dismisses it, so it ends up blocking content further on in my test, causing it to fail.  I tried the Cypress iframe plugin, the `cy.wrap()` solution, and the custom command, none of them work for clicking the close icon.  I can find the iframe no problem, but can't find any elements in the iframe.

[image]

```
cy.get('iframe[class="intercom-zsm3q8 e1o2sc8n0"]')
            .iframe('body span[class="intercom-anchor intercom-1tdusvr e12dv51w1"]').click()
```

Error:

```
cy.click() failed because it requires a DOM element.

The subject received was:

  > {}
```

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148770/unable-to-get-element-which-is-in-under-a-iframe-in-cypress/62149357#62149357?

Comment: As mentioned, I tried `cy.wrap`, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this code snippet and see whether it works or not. Recently I have worked in a project interacting with iframe elements.

```js
cy.get("iframe").then( $iframe =>

const $doc = $iframe.contents();

cy.wait(3000).wrap( $doc.find("write the class name here") ).click({ force: true })

});
```